# http POST request response with "status": 200 but with an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, react-native

I am trying to use an API with HTTP POST request and It seems to work but when I get the response it's empty.

The API should receive `base64` encoded image inside the body.

The argument  `imageToRead` coming from a promise returned with the `Camera` component from `react-native-camera`. I'm not sure maybe the problem there?

This is the content:
`imageToRead = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/01B81FC9-B171-11GB-9B48-9D06F89B175A/Documents/3A997ACD-D63C-41BD-9041-FDB834A0672A.jpg"`

This API can also receive `formData` files and that how I tested it with and it went great in Node environment. But because my application is a native iOS application, I had to use other tools (like React Native) and can not use the same ones.

**Code to test the API in Node:**

```
var formData = {image: fs.createReadStream('/Users/Desktop/APITest/img/testOCR8.jpg')};
request.post({
url:'${url}', 
formData: formData},
(err, httpResponse, body) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    console.log(body);

});
```

You can see I use `fs.createReadStream` from the `fs` module to create stream of the file and then use it inside the request body. 
I couldn't replicate the same thing using React Native (if you have a solution so I could do it with React Native it would be even better!!)

So I tried deferent way and tried to encode the file I got from the `camera.capture()` method that come with `react-native-camera` to `base64` and to place it inside the body but the response I got is empty without any errors, just an empty object.

**Code with React Native:**

```
recognise = (imageToRead) => {
    RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(imageToRead , 'base64')
      .then((data) => {
        fetch('${url}',{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: data // the body contain the encoded image
        })
      .then((res) => {  // promise returned with the response from the API
        console.log(`i am the base64Image: ${data}`)
        console.log('i am response', res)
      })  
      .catch((errInFetch) => { // catch any error in the API
        console.log('i am error:', errInFetch)
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

**Response:**

```
{ type: 'default',
  status: 200,
  ok: true,
  statusText: undefined,
  headers: 
   { map: 
      { server: [ 'nginx/1.10.3' ],
        'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset="utf-8"' ],
        'access-control-allow-origin': [ '*' ],
        date: [ 'Thu, 10 May 2018 10:17:48 GMT' ],
        'access-control-allow-headers': [ 'x-requested-with' ],
        'content-encoding': [ 'gzip' ],
        'content-length': [ '237' ],
        connection: [ 'keep-alive' ] } },
  url: 'https://api.openalpr.com/v2/recognize_bytes?secret_key=key&country=eu',
  _bodyInit: 
   { _data: 
      { size: 371,
        blobId: '5080ACA4-5D13-469C-B755-96B06A161FC6',
        type: 'application/json',
        offset: 0,
        name: 'recognize_bytes' } },
  _bodyBlob: 
   { _data: 
      { size: 371,
        blobId: '5080ACA4-5D13-469C-B755-96B06A161FC6',
        type: 'application/json',
        offset: 0,
        name: 'recognize_bytes' } } }
```

I hope someone can help with this. I have struggle with it for so long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` returns a `promise` containing the response (a Response object). then you again need to parse that using `response.json()` which returns promise resolving `JSON`.

```
fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    headers: {
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
```

for more info : [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: it worked, thank you!!! i was struggling with it so much although I still don't get the data I supposed to. The response is right and everything but there is some data related to the image that is missing (like the `  results: []`) there is a chance there isnt an actual image that being processed? or there is no way and it would throw some error? note that I checked the stream after converting the path to base64 and it is indeed return this LONG string of letters that is the base64 file I guess. (just trying to cover all the possibilities) can you suggest some test maybe? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
      .then((res) => { 
        console.log(`i am the base64Image: ${data}`)
        console.log('i am response', res)
        return res.json();
      })  
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((errInFetch) => { // catch any error in the API
        console.log('i am error:', errInFetch)
      })
```

Fetch response body returns a Promise that will be resolved by json().

So you can get your real data from `res.json()`.

Answer (score -1):

The 200 status is for a success get http request. Your API should return status 201 for post with a message instead of 200, for example:

```
res.status(201).send(data);
```

[full example](http://codeoverflow.ebigdatai.com/codeoverflow/index.php/2018/04/22/restful-testing-and-code-coverage-using-mocha-chai-istanbul-nyc-fs-node-js-and-express/)

[also, you can look at the status 201 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201)